# Continue the Pattern #5

Tags: pattern

Can you complete this pattern?

[image: A pattern of consecutive shapes that seems to be growing smaller]

Comment: $(+1)$ Hahah please continue to make more of these. Love it!

Comment: Wow! Thank you so much! I enjoy making them! I am doing it to get some more traction on our School's FB page, but looks like even the simple ones are a bit above the majority FB people's puzzling ability :P Seems people are just not willing to take a few minutes to stop and think...

Comment: I would recommend either visually splitting the patterns and answers in the future (horizontal line or distance) or making the Letters appear beneath or above the solution suggestions consistently. i thought that A, B and C belonged to the things above them, because D, E and F obviously did so. Which made the puzzle really odd at first.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Answer:

> A

Explanation:

> each row consists of three polyominoes that together have the ability to tile a 5x5 square. The first option is the only one fitting this pattern.

Answer (score 7):

My answer is:

> A

Explanation:

> All three parts combine together to form a 5*5 square. You may need to rotate the parts to fit in as second part in second row need to rotate to fit on top of part a and similarly part c need to rotate as well

Solution:

> Rotate 2nd part upside down and fit in 1st part so you left with blank space where option A fits well!

Please ask if explanation not clear;)

Comment: This appears to be the same as my answer.

Comment: Yes, i got it now that time i didn't get your reasoning my bad, and i was in too hurry to post mine;)

Answer (score 4):

Answer:

> F

General explanation:

> In every step, each column is replaced by a column of size smaller size that exists in the current formation. The shortest column is (are) removed and the remaining columns are shoved together.

Specific steps to obtain the third figure:

> In the second step, the outer columns (height 2) are replaced by the middle column (height 1). The middle column has only one block (the smallest), so it is removed all together. The two outer columns are shoved together to obtain the answer.

Comment: $(+1)$ Every other answer is the same (although different reasonings), but yours is different :)

Answer (score 3):

Answer:

> It's A (Edit, mistyped)

Explanation:

> We're searching for a piece, that makes a square with figure nr.1 and nr.2.

Comment: Welcome to [puzzling.se]! This answer was already given (twice), there is no need to repeat it.

Comment: Doesn't matter.

Comment: If every good answer was given three times, where would we be? I'm afraid I can't agree that it doesn't matter. Personal opinion : ).

Answer (score 2):

Answer:

> A

Explanation:

> The pattern is that the shape in the 3rd column of each row is the size difference between the shape in the 1st column of the shape in the row and the 2nd column of that row.